# $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is continuous and periodic ($f(x+1)=f(x)$), prove that $\exists m\in\mathbb{R}: f(m+\pi)=f(m)$.

Tags: real-analysis, periodic-functions

### What I have got:

Let's take
$$g(x):=f(x+\pi)-f(x)$$
Now we must show that $\exists m\in\mathbb{R}:g(m)=0$. We see that as $f$ is periodic, $g$ is also a periodic function. Now let's suppose that $\forall x\in\mathbb{R}$ $g(x)\neq 0$. This means that $g(x)$ is strictly positive or negative. Now, because $f$ is periodic and continuous, it has $\max$ and $\min$. Is $f$ is strictly positive and $f(m)$ is $\max$, we get g(x)<0.

### Is the last sentence a contradiction? How should the proof go? Am I approaching the problem right?

Comment: Yes, this is essentially correct.  Note that after defining $g$, you can skip a lot of the words you wrote.  Just let $m$ be such that $f(m)$ is maximal.  Then $g(m)\le0$, and $g(m-\pi)\ge0$.

Comment: This is correct. The assumption that  $g$ is always positive (or always negative) leads to a contradiction when $f(m)=\max f$  (or $f(m)=\min f$ ) so there must exist $x$ with $g(x)=0.$.... &  $ f$ attains its  max and min is  because $\{f(x): x\in [0,1]\}$ contains all the values of $f,$  and the function $f|_{[0,1]}$ ... (which is $f$ restricted to the domain $[0,1])$... is continuous so it attains its sup and inf.